# Delphi 10 TPaintbox code places bitmap on the form instead of paintbox

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

Hi i have the following code to add an image from a Timage that for now is populated from a blob. My issue is this code does not add the image to the paintbox but rather to the form.

```
var
  RectangleCanvas, RectanglePicture: TRectF;
  BlobStream: TStream;
begin
      BlobStream := qrypunchsheetitemphoto.CreateBlobStream(qrypunchsheetitemphoto.FieldByName('Photo'),TBlobStreamMode.bmRead);
      imgviewimage.Bitmap.LoadFromStream(BlobStream);
      fdrawbox:= TMyPaintBox.Create(panel1);
      fdrawbox.Canvas.BeginScene;
      fdrawbox.BitmapStamp := imgviewimage.Bitmap;
      fdrawbox.Height := imgviewimage.Bitmap.Height;
      fdrawbox.Width := imgviewimage.Bitmap.Width;
      RectangleCanvas := RectF(10, 10, imgviewimage.Bitmap.Width, imgviewimage.Bitmap.Height);
      RectanglePicture := RectF(10, 10, imgviewimage.Bitmap.Width, imgviewimage.Bitmap.Height);
           fdrawbox.Canvas.DrawBitmap(imgviewimage.Bitmap, RectangleCanvas , RectanglePicture, 1);
           fdrawbox.Canvas.EndScene;
          fdrawbox.BringToFront;
           BlobStream.Free;
          TabControl1.ActiveTab := tabViewImage;
     end;
end;
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. It appears to me, that the `TPaintBox` you are using is not an ordinary one, as its class is called `TMyPaintBox`. How is that different? I also don't understand what exactly you mean by *...does not add the image to the paintbox...*. Is this related to features you have added to `TMyPaintBox`? A `TPaintBox` doesn't have the ability keep images. Did you read the documentation yet? *...TPaintBox requires an application to draw the image directly on a canvas*. You need to explain better what the actual issue is.

Comment: Oh, and btw, do not use `with` statements if you don't know how they work. Read the docs ´about this too.

Comment: Hi the Tmypaintbox was an example i found and adapted. I hope it is similar  .

Comment: i can click on the paintbox after selecting an image and it is rendered on the paintbox, i can then scribble all over it. What i want to achieve is do the same when i select an image from a list, but as i say it does not render to the paintbox but rather to the form.

Comment: perhaps i might use the delphi tpaintbox and see if the issue is in the Tmypaintbox unit. at the end of markup i would save the bitmap image back to my DB thanks

Comment: Please show [mcve]

Comment: Use the "edit" button (below the tags) to edit your question with an MCVE as David asked you to. Your comments did not really clarify your issue. Probably you have a wrong understanding of what a `TPaintBox` is.

Comment: I don't use Delphi nor FMX, but aren't you forgetting to set the Parent property? Something like fdrawbox.Parent := panel1;

Answer (score 1):

The FMX Paintbox is different to older Delphi Paintboxes. Previously you could put a Paintbox anywhere on your form and start drawing. The results would be within the confines of the Paintbox where you placed it.

The FMX Paintbox isn't like that and *I don't understand their reasoning*. I've been told it has a something to do with cross-platform compatibility and how devices handle canvas operations.

You can verify canvas width for yourself easily enough.

If you have a form width of 640 pixels and place a 50 x 50 Paintbox in the middle you'd expect drawing to occur in the middle.

Check it yourself;

```
ShowMessage(FloatToStr(Paintbox1.Width)); // Result will be 50
```

Now check Paintbox1.Canvas.Width and you'll get a different result.

```
ShowMessage(IntToStr(Paintbox1.Canvas.Width)); // Result is 640
```

When you pass parameters to drawing functions you need to take this into account and offset accordingly. I have read something about parental clipping having some effect, but I've not seen it work.

Another potential solution is to use a TPanel and draw on it's canvas.

Comment: Hi Craig,
Thanks for that it would be nice if Delphi supplied a working example seeing the component is has now been altered for other platforms. I have no experience with graphics components all DB previously. for $3000 AUD this is a bit frustrating, i might pursue the Tpanel option
anyway thanks and regards

Geoff

Comment: @Geoff We pay way toooo much for software in Australia. There is a demo of stuff, perhaps including (I think) the PainBox here: [link](http://sourceforge.net/p/radstudiodemos/code/HEAD/tree/branches/RADStudio_Tokyo/Object%20Pascal/Multi-Device%20Samples/User%20Interface/ControlsDesktop)